# Gulp wait until other function is done

Tags: gulp

I'm using gulp to build html/css/ts with browser-sync for livereload. The problem is when first builds, building html is much faster than ts build so when browser-sync runs, it fails to load compiled JavaScript.

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const watchify = require('watchify');
const tsify = require('tsify');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


function swallowError (error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
    this.emit('end');
}

function buildHtml() {
    return gulp.src('./src/html/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
}

function buildCss() {
    return gulp.src('./src/css/app.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function buildScript() {
    let opts = Object.assign({}, watchify.args, { debug: true });
    let b = watchify(opts)
    .add('./src/ts/index.tsx')
    .on('update', bundle)
    .on('log', gutil.log)
    .plugin(tsify, {
        jsx: 'react'
    });

    function bundle() {
        return b.bundle()
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe(source('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
    }

    return bundle();
}

gulp.task('default', () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: './build'
    });


    gulp.watch('./src/html/**.html', buildHtml);
    gulp.watch('./src/css/**.css', buildCss);

    gulp.watch('./build/index.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./build/index.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);

    return merge([
        buildHtml(),
        buildScript(),
        buildCss()
    ]);
});
```

You can see the functions for build each resources, buildHtml, buildScript, buildCss. They are working great, but I don't know how to execute buildScript after buildHtml with merge-stream in this case.

You can see the 4 watch codes, which for livereload of course, watching build/index.js not working on first builds. I mean on first build, first build directory will created and html will be there also, but not index.js created yet. And this moment, browser-sync will activate, run this application but script wasn't there, so it failed. After compiled script, browser-sync not reload, looks like generated new file isn't trigger onchange event at all.

This will resolve for refresh website with F5, or just restart the gulp, but I want to fix this problem. Any advice will very appreciate it!!

Comment: gulp.task("default", gulp.series (buildScript, buildCss,buildHtml, () => etc. ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by run browser-sync after transpile is done.